# Как увидеть колличество траффика на интерфейсе cisco 2911 за сутки?

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios

Всем добрый день, есть cisco 2911 нужна информация по количеству трафика проходящего через внешний интерфейс за месяц и за сутки. Netflow настроил, как видеть информацию не понимаю.

Comment: Я подобное делаю с помощью SNMP и zabbix. Заббикс опрашивает по snmp счетчики интерфейса (ifHCInOctets, ifHCOutOctets) раз в сутки, вычисляет разницу счетчиков, запоминает, рисует график входящего/исходящего трафика.

Comment: поделитесь oid для счетчиков

Comment: Out - `IF-MIB::ifHCOutOctets.5010`, где 5010 индекс нужного мне интерфейса, у вас, соответственно, другой индекс. In - `IF-MIB::ifHCInOctets.5010`. Полная цифровая нотация: .1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.6.5010, .1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.10.5010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В случае с NetFlow вам надо чем-то получать и сохранять от циски эти самые flows.
Например, с помощью flow-capture из пакета `flow-tools`.
После сохранения полученные файлы можно анализировать с помощью flow-cat, flow-nfilter, flow-print и flow-stats.

На выходе получите практически бухгалтерскую точность.

Если же достаточно точности «плюс-минус пара процентов», то описанный в комментариях к вопросу метод с заббиксом и/или SNMP весьма неплох.